# Flattening folders

Tags: arrays, json, recursion, flatten

I've been having a problem trying to flatten the folders in this format:
for example we have this folder structure. The names should be changed as on the right side, whether as the format of each folder should be flattened.
The goal is for the folders to be flattened and each of their names should be for example:
If A has a subfolder B and subfolder C, C's name should be: A/B/C, B's name should be A/B.

```
{
  id: "0",
  name: null,
  parentId: null,
  folderType: "chatMessages",
  folders: [
    {
      id: 3195588631115178,
      name: "Testfolder",
      parentId: null,
      folderType: "chatMessages",
      folders: [
        {
          id: "3195588620182363",
          name: "Subfolder",
          parentId: "3195588631115178",
          folderType: "chatMessages",
          folders: [
            {
              id: "3206824598737435",
              name: "Interesting",
              parentId: "3195588620182363",
              folderType: "chat",
              folders: [],
              items: [
                {
                  id: "3208409930553392",
                  name: "Message",
                  folderId: "3206824598737435",
                  updated: "2022-05-27T07:28:40.450Z",
                  frontendFolderId: null,
                  text: "<p>This is an HTML with Image.</p>",
                  keywords: "test",
                  subject: "What kind of subject",
                  slashCommand: "test",
                  language: "en-US",
                  setupItemId: "3208409930553392",
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
          items: [
            {
              id: "3195595211854821",
              name: "Message in subfolder",
              folderId: "3195588620182363",
              updated: "2022-05-19T12:05:39.503Z",
              frontendFolderId: null,
              text: "Message in subfolder",
              keywords: "test",
              subject: "Message in subfolder",
              slashCommand: "sub",
              language: "bn-BD",
              setupItemId: "3195595211854821",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
      items: [],
    },
  ],
  items: [
    {
      id: "2888102250465731",
      name: "bye",
      folderId: null,
      updated: "2022-05-25T11:15:36.367Z",
      frontendFolderId: null,
      text: "Thanks for contacting us.  Please do not hesitate to contact us again if we can be of further assistance.",
      keywords: "bye",
      subject: null,
      slashCommand: null,
      language: null,
      setupItemId: "2888102250465731",
    },
  ],
}
```

UPDATE: How can I create an array of every item and their id, folderId and text properties?
I want to achieve this format:

```
{
  id: "3195595211854821",
  folderId: "3195588620182363",
  text: "Message in subfolder",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this gets you started? Here `flat` is a recursive generator that yields array paths of `name` attributes -

```js
function *flat({ name = "", folders = [], items = [] }) {
  yield [name]
  for (const x of [...folders, ...items])
    for (const path of flat(x))
      yield [name, ...path]
}
```

```js
for (const path of flat(data))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

```
/Testfolder
/Testfolder/Subfolder
/Testfolder/Subfolder/Interesting
/Testfolder/Subfolder/Interesting/Message
/Testfolder/Subfolder/Message in subfolder
/bye
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const data  = {id:"0",name:null,parentId:null,folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:3195588631115178,name:"Testfolder",parentId:null,folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:"3195588620182363",name:"Subfolder",parentId:"3195588631115178",folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:"3206824598737435",name:"Interesting",parentId:"3195588620182363",folderType:"chat",folders:[],items:[{id:"3208409930553392",name:"Message",folderId:"3206824598737435",updated:"2022-05-27T07:28:40.450Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"<p>This is an HTML with Image.</p>",keywords:"test",subject:"What kind of subject",slashCommand:"test",language:"en-US",setupItemId:"3208409930553392",},],},],items:[{id:"3195595211854821",name:"Message in subfolder",folderId:"3195588620182363",updated:"2022-05-19T12:05:39.503Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"Message in subfolder",keywords:"test",subject:"Message in subfolder",slashCommand:"sub",language:"bn-BD",setupItemId:"3195595211854821",},],},],items:[],},],items:[{id:"2888102250465731",name:"bye",folderId:null,updated:"2022-05-25T11:15:36.367Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"Thanks for contacting us.  Please do not hesitate to contact us again if we can be of further assistance.",keywords:"bye",subject:null,slashCommand:null,language:null,setupItemId:"2888102250465731",},],}

function *flat({ name = "", folders = [], items = [] }) {
  yield [name]
  for (const x of [...folders, ...items])
    for (const path of flat(x))
      yield [name, ...path]
}

for (const path of flat(data))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Here's a second option that builds a path of nodes objects, not just the `name` properties. This gives the caller the option to use any node properties when constructing the output path -

```js
function *flat(t = {}) {
  yield [t]
  for (const x of [...t.folders ?? [], ...t.items ?? []])
    for (const path of flat(x))
      yield [t, ...path]
}
```

```js
for (const path of flat(data))
  console.log(
    path.map(node => `${node.name ?? ""}<#${node.id}>`).join("/")
  )
```

```
<#0>
<#0>/Testfolder<#3195588631115178>
<#0>/Testfolder<#3195588631115178>/Subfolder<#3195588620182363>
<#0>/Testfolder<#3195588631115178>/Subfolder<#3195588620182363>/Interesting<#3206824598737435>
<#0>/Testfolder<#3195588631115178>/Subfolder<#3195588620182363>/Interesting<#3206824598737435>/Message<#3208409930553392>
<#0>/Testfolder<#3195588631115178>/Subfolder<#3195588620182363>/Message in subfolder<#3195595211854821>
<#0>/bye<#2888102250465731>
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the snippet below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
const data  = {id:"0",name:null,parentId:null,folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:3195588631115178,name:"Testfolder",parentId:null,folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:"3195588620182363",name:"Subfolder",parentId:"3195588631115178",folderType:"chatMessages",folders:[{id:"3206824598737435",name:"Interesting",parentId:"3195588620182363",folderType:"chat",folders:[],items:[{id:"3208409930553392",name:"Message",folderId:"3206824598737435",updated:"2022-05-27T07:28:40.450Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"<p>This is an HTML with Image.</p>",keywords:"test",subject:"What kind of subject",slashCommand:"test",language:"en-US",setupItemId:"3208409930553392",},],},],items:[{id:"3195595211854821",name:"Message in subfolder",folderId:"3195588620182363",updated:"2022-05-19T12:05:39.503Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"Message in subfolder",keywords:"test",subject:"Message in subfolder",slashCommand:"sub",language:"bn-BD",setupItemId:"3195595211854821",},],},],items:[],},],items:[{id:"2888102250465731",name:"bye",folderId:null,updated:"2022-05-25T11:15:36.367Z",frontendFolderId:null,text:"Thanks for contacting us.  Please do not hesitate to contact us again if we can be of further assistance.",keywords:"bye",subject:null,slashCommand:null,language:null,setupItemId:"2888102250465731",},],}

function *flat(t = {}) {
  yield [t]
  for (const x of [...t.folders ?? [], ...t.items ?? []])
    for (const path of flat(x))
      yield [t, ...path]
}

for (const path of flat(data))
  console.log(
    path.map(node => `${node.name ?? ""}<#${node.id}>`).join("/")
  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped me a lot. Another thing I want to ask is how I can map each folder name with its id. For example: /Testfolder/Subfolder/Message in subfolder with 3195595211854821?

Comment: And sorry another question, how can i store the whole output from the log? I want to use it to be able to manipulate the data

Comment: `console.log` is the effect. If you want it to be something else, like `myarr.push(doSomething(path))`, you can do that instead. If the goal is to put all lines in an array, look at the built-in function `Array.from` for efficiently converting iterable to array. If you have more questions, maybe you can update this question, or ask a new one and link me :D